# how to make first letter capital in inputfield after saving the record or before saving the record?

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputfield

I am trying to give first letter capital in input field value. How to make first letter capital  after saving the record or before saving the record?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented similar.
What I did is I installed the below app, which is free, and working great,

[Capitalization](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5YhNEAV)